# unix - how to construct IFS for passing in context of file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Am I constructing this properly? I can't figure how to debug this.
Basically, I'm trying to pass in a text file (login.info):

```
foo
bar
```

To this shell script to be used as parameters like so:

```
#/usr/bin/ksh

#Base dir
BASEDIR=/home/scripts
export BASEDIR;

#Key
KEY=$BASEDIR/login.info
export KEY;

IFS="
"
arr=( $(<$KEY) )
echo "username=${arr[0]} password=${arr[1]}"
```

Getting this error:

```
./tst.sh[12]: Syntax error at line 12 : `(' is not expected.
```

Comment: It works for me on OS X 10.6.8. ksh version is `Version M 1993-12-28 s+`

Comment: Could it be my OS - HP-UX B.11.31? Is there another way to write this?

Comment: What's with the `export`s? By the looks of this, they are unnecessary (unless you need them to be visible to child processes later on in the script, of course).

Comment: You forgot the `!` in `#!/usr/bin/ksh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your version of `ksh` doesn't understand `(...)` in array assignment. Maybe this will work better:

```
set -A arr $(cat $KEY)
```